# Changing ng-hide styling depending on element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Right now, I have a page where I'm using ng-show and ng-hide on different elements. On some of the elements I need `visibility: hidden!important;` so that it will still take space on the page. On other elements, I need them to disappear completely with `display: none!important;`.

Is there a way I can have different attributes for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using ng-style instead of ng-show/ng-hide and conditionally apply classes to the elements. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

You want to create this kind of directive:

```
.directive('ngVisible', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(attr.ngVisible, function (visible) {
            element.css('visibility', visible ? 'visible!important' : 'hidden!important');
        });
    };
})
```

You will choose between `ng-visible` and `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, regarding your use case.